# how to use t4mvc routing helper with custom route constraints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

im using t4mvc in my current project and am trying to use the routing helper included however when i try to use custom constraints as below

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        "def_filtered_reports_route",
        "reports/{samplePoint}/{fromDate}/{toDate}",
        MVC.Report.Results(null, null, null),
        new
        {
            samplePoint = new SamplePointExistsConstraint(),
            fromDate = new DateTimeConstraint(),
            toDate = new DateTimeConstraint()
        }
        );
```

it throws an `ArgumentException` stating `An item with the same key has already been added.`

if i write it like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "def_filtered_reports_route",
    "reports/{samplePoint}/{fromDate}/{toDate}",
    MVC.Report.Results(null, null, null) );
```

or like this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
           "def_filtered_reports_route",
           "reports/{samplePoint}/{fromDate}/{toDate}",
           new
           {
               controller = "Report",
               action = "Results",
               fromDate = "",
               toDate = "",
               samplePoint = ""
           },
           new
           {
               fromDate = new DateTimeConstraint(),
               toDate = new DateTimeConstraint(),
               samplePoint = new SamplePointExistsConstraint()
           });
```

it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing or does t4mvc not support custom constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing an extra null for the defaults before the constraints. e.g.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           "def_filtered_reports_route",
           "reports/{samplePoint}/{fromDate}/{toDate}",
           MVC.Report.Results(null, null, null),
           null /*defaults*/,
           new {
               samplePoint = new SamplePointExistsConstraint(),
               fromDate = new DateTimeConstraint(),
               toDate = new DateTimeConstraint()
           }
           );
```

Comment: if im using the helper do i still need to define controller and action in the anonymous object with the default values or is the Helper only designed to break if the action is deleted

Comment: If you use the helper, then passing MVC.Report.Results(...) does indeed remove the need to pass the controller/action in the default anonymous object.

Comment: so just pass your defaults with the helper and just toss a null to the default way then sounds good thanks david